# Stack cookie bypass demonstration 2 : Virtual Function call -- Can't compile debug build in VS2008 - 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

```
// gsvtable.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
class Foo {
  public:
  void __declspec(noinline) gs3(char* src)
  {
   char buf[8];
   strcpy(buf, src);
   bar(); // virtual function call
  }
   virtual void __declspec(noinline) bar()
   {
   }
 };
int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.gs3(
  "AAAA"
  "BBBB"
  "CCCC"
  "DDDD"
  "EEEE"
  "FFFF");
 return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the above code in Visual Studio 2008 I get this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x004114f0 in gsvtable.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x45454545.
```

When I click break it breaks on:

```
11:    bar(); // virtual function call
004114ED 8B 45 F4         mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
==> 004114F0 8B 10            mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]
```

Registers:

```
EAX = 45454545 EBX = 7FFD9000 ECX = 00415758 EDX = 00000000 ESI = 00000000 
EDI = 0012FE84 EIP = 004114F0 ESP = 0012FD98 EBP = 0012FE84 EFL = 00000202 

45454545 = ????????
```

My compile command line arguments:

```
/Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp"Debug\gsvtable.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /nologo /c /ZI /TP /errorReport:prompt
```

and the linker arguments:

```
/OUT:"C:\Documents and Settings\pca\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\gsvtable\Debug\gsvtable.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Debug\gsvtable.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"c:\Documents and Settings\pca\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\gsvtable\Debug\gsvtable.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib
```

The above code is from https://web.archive.org/web/20150425014136/https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/09/21/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-6-bypassing-stack-cookies-safeseh-hw-dep-and-aslr/ section "Stack cookie bypass demonstration 2 : Virtual Function call" where I am supposed to enable GS protection (its already enabled by default).

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make this code compile so I can follow along in the tutorial? How many arguments does this application take?

Googling the error code indicates something along the lines of it happens when a pointer has not been set to anything. But it doesn't get me anywhere closer to getting this app to compile.

Comment: This is not C, but C++

Comment: Are you getting an error when *compiling* or *running* this code?

Comment: I get this error when I click the green play button to create a debug build. So I assume it is when compiling.

Comment: @Moshe Were you able to compile it in VS? What arguments did you put in the Debug window - Command arguments?

Comment: ***What am I doing wrong?*** Copying more than 7 characters into a buffer large enough to hold only 7 + null terminator. Remember that "AAAA" "BBBB" .. get concatenated together to form 1 character string that is passed to foo.gs3().

Comment: The whole exercise seems to be an exercise exploit UB.

Comment: This is not a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

`45454545` in the `EAX` register clearly isn't a valid memory address. So moving the contents of that "address" causes the access violation.

The cause is that you copy a too long string to the only 8 bytes of buf.

Comment: Okay but how am I supposed to compile the above code so I can open it in windbg to follow along in the tutorial?

Comment: Use the debugger to check the code and stack are EXACTLY as in the eample.

Comment: @paul-ogilive But there is no .exe file in my \Debug folder to open in the first place.

Comment: Your output showed that `gsvtable.exe` does exist somewhere on your filesystem. Otherwise it would not execute at all.